# Resize Datagridview to fill panel size

Tags: c#

I have panel and datagridview  in Form I put datagridview over the panel 
when form load i have to resize the datagridview  according the panel size and cover the panel so that will not show empty area in Panel
I tried doc style fill but its not working still showing empty are in panel

```
this.dgvMasterApproval.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

how can i resize datagridview to fill the panel

Comment: Are you agree that it is empty area from panel. Maybe it is from form?

Comment: If the DGV is inside the Panel it fills it with your code. If there are 'emtpy' spaces then either the Panel doesn't fill the form or the columns and rows don't fill the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the datagridview to adjust its width and height when the Form resized, you need to set also the property Dock of the Panel to Fill.
Assuming the panel is named Panel1, add this line to your code:

```
this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Moreover if you want also columns populating the grid to fill all the width of the grid, set AutoSizeColumnsMode property of the grid to Fill:

```
this.dgvMasterApproval.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```